# Limit the size of the input text in a PLAIN_MESSAGE JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am creating a Dialog box using the `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` method with the `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE` option type. This displays a confirmation popup with a free text input field. I need the text to be 256 characters maximum but can't find any option to limit it when declaring the dialog.

At the moment I test the lenght of the String returned and truncate it if it is too long:

```
private void showConfirmationPopup(Component parent) {
    String title = "";
    String message = "";
    String defaultComment = "";
    // Open an Input Dialog with a Text field
    Object comment = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            parent,
            message, 
            title, 
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null,
            null,
            defaultComment);

    if(comment != null) {
        String inputComment = (String)comment;
        if(inputComment.length()>256) {
            inputComment = inputComment.substring(0, 256);
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to set the limit when declaring the dialog or if there is a clever trick to achieve it, so I don't have to do the check afterwards.

Comment: The short answer is: if you're using the convenience methods to create the dialog, you cannot do what you want.

Comment: @SeanBright I'm afraid you're right :)

Answer (score 1):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#stayup).

It shows how you can edit the text entered and prevent the dialog from closing if valid data is not entered.

Edit:

You could try accessing the text field of the option pane:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class OptionPaneInput2
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        JTextField label = new JTextField("How old are you?");
        label.addAncestorListener( new AncestorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent e)
            {
                Component component = e.getComponent();
                Container parent = component.getParent();
                JTextField textField = (JTextField)parent.getComponent(1);
                System.out.println("added");
            }

            @Override
            public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent e) {}

        });


        //  Simple text field for input:

        String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            frame,
            label);

        frame.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

By specifying the message as a JLabel you can be notified when the label is added to the dialog and then you can access the input text field and add a `DocumentFilter` to the `Document` of the text field and perform your required editing.

See the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for a filter that limits the number of characters displayed.

If this is still too creative for you then I would suggest you simply create your own custom JDialog. This really is the best approach.

Comment: After reading it, it is not about the showInputDialog method, it is about creating a custom OptionPane and a custom Dialog, which is not really what I am looking for. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: `which is not really what I am looking for.` - yes, but there is no direct way to access the internals of the option pane. See edit for another hack.